# What is the best method for locating missing images

Tags: html, css, broken-image

I have got to sift through multiple websites and look for misssing images, the problem I am facing is that, they are very hard to find.

Just looking through the code and comparing it to the image directory is not an option, as there are several image folder references, with a large number of images inside each.

My normal method just involves checking through pages using internet explorer, as it shows a nice missing image box, however if the image width/height has been set to something small (small sprite images that have been set in CSS etc), then they are nearly impossible to notice.

Comment: By broken images you mean missing? or you actually mean a corrupted image file?

Comment: Missing, yes sorry -edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Open chrome and do "CTRL + Shift + j" you will see a panel with missing images and all...